# Route to last known state of the tab

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have GUI which has couple of tabs. Under each tab, exists a table which allows sorting and searching and query params are mapped in the URL to query params. I'd like to preserve the last known state (along with URL) of each tab before navigating away from any tab and when click on a tab I'd like to be taken back the last known URL of the tab I was on before I left it. Each tab has a different path.

For example, let's say I'm on Tab_1 `(/tab1)`, I search for "hello", table filters `(/tab1?q=hello)` and switch to another tab Tab_2. When I click on Tab_1, I want to go back to search state `(/tab1?q=hello)` with corresponding query params in the URL.

I have implemented `RouterReuseStrategy` to cache component state, but my components watch for query params, since there are no query params when I navigate back, the component is re-initialized. I believe if I somehow manage to set  URL with query params, the component will show the correct cached state. I just cannot figure how to achieve that.

Any suggestion/recommendation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not save the URL and/or query params to local storage? Then load the last state from local storage during component creation?

Comment: Perhaps I can, but I'm exploring if there is a way to do it with "in-memory" way